# What is the timeline of the connection of the soul to the body after death?

Tags: death, soul

Speaking to the Rabbi who runs the *chevra kadisha* in my neighborhood recently, regarding the pending cremation of the mother of a friend, he mentioned several interesting concepts with respect to the connection of the soul (it's not clear to me whether we are speaking of the *nefesh*, *ruach*, or *neshama*, or all three) to its lifeless body. I did not, at the time, find it pertinent to prod him for references.

I am hoping the distinguished members of **mi yodea** could source, and possibly expand on (any of) the following items:

1. Immediately after death, the soul is very preoccupied with the care of the body. It feels anguish until the body is properly laid to rest.
2. The "safest" place for  the body is the earth (from the perspective of assuaging the soul's sorrow).
3. The soul does not begin its "ascent" until the body is safeguarded. (Obviously, this has **deep** implications for all forms of un-buried bodies. How long does this interim period last?)
4. Is there a source (that is accessible to the novice) that deals with the timeline and experience of the soul immediately after death and beyond?

Comment: http://acheinu.co.il/?CategoryID=206&ArticleID=3637

Comment: @GershonGold Pretty excellent article. Mentioned the expiation of "חיבוט הקבר" (the atonement that comes from the body decomposing, a year-long cycle, more or less). I wonder what happens to the soul when it doesn't have the opportunity to experience this.